# Best practice for documenting std::function parameters

Tags: c++

When declaring a type using `std::function`, I find that I miss being able to assign parameter names to the template arguments.  For example, I find this plain function pointer type declaration:

```
typedef void (*ArcCallback)(
  void *object, 
  double x_start, double y_start, 
  double x_finish, double y_finish, 
  double x_center, double y_center, 
  bool counterclockwise);
```

to be more readable than this `std::function` type declaration:

```
typedef std::function<void(
  void *,
  double, double,
  double, double,
  double, double,
  bool)> ArcCallback;
```

Despite the flexibility that comes with the use of `std::function` (for example, being able to assign a lambda or the result of a `std::bind` call), I miss the parameter names.  Of course I can add comments to the `std::function` declaration, but the result is clunky.  More importantly, I don't think IDEs would use those comments to provide parameter hints.

How do other experienced C++ practitioners document the purpose of template parameters to `std::function`?  Is there a precedent set by widely-used libraries that heavily use such types?

Comment: I am torn on accepting an answer to this question.  AnT points out that my premise was false -- I can already name my template arguments the same way that I name my function pointer arguments.  Josh Kelley describes a stylistically better way to name the function arguments.  The arguments get named either way, but Josh's way results in the IDE feedback I was hoping for, and the argument names are visible at the call site.  So I accepted Josh's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular code, the problem isn't so much that `std::function` has no good way to document parameters, the problem is that 8 parameters is probably too much for *any* function.  Introducing additional types can go a long way toward cleaning this up.

```
typedef void* CallbackObject;

struct Point {
  double x;
  double y;
};

enum CircularDirection {
  CLOCKWISE,
  COUNTERCLOCKWISE
};

struct ArcCallbackParam {
  CallbackObject object;
  Point start;
  Point finish;
  Point center;
  CircularDirection direction;
};

typedef std::function<void(const ArcCallbackParam&)> ArcCallback;
```

**Edit**: I realize this doesn't directly answer your question. To answer your question, I'm not aware of any "solutions" beyond commenting the arguments, but adding types and typedefs can help a lot.

Comment: ["8 parameters is probably too much for any function"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: From an IDE perspective this has the advantage of forcing the creation of a structure with field names that the IDE knows so you get hinting while coding.  And the purpose of the fields is more explicit in the resulting code.

Comment: @black - Fair point, although 15-20 year old C APIs are probably not the best example for how to design an interface.

Answer (score 4):

Parameter names in your original `ArcCallback` typedef are there solely for self-documentation purposes. Since you have a habit of using "redundant" parameter names for self-documentation purposes, why don't you do the same thing in `std::function` case as well?

```
typedef std::function<void (
  void *object, 
  double x_start, double y_start, 
  double x_finish, double y_finish, 
  double x_center, double y_center, 
  bool counterclockwise)> ArcCallback;
```

The language does not prohibit doing so.

Comment: That is interesting;  I didn't know that was possible.  I just confirmed that it works with VC++13.  If this is valid according to the standard, then I will probably start naming my template parameters when there is a short parameter list.  At least for the Visual Studio IDE, naming the parameters this way does not confer any IDE hinting benefits, though.